# How to push a set of arrays into main array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular8

I want to push some arrays into the main array in single function. Here is the example :

```js
let MainArr = [
 {
  "date": "2021-02-24T18:30:00.000Z",
  "age": "9",
  "id": 74,
  "time": 4.00 },
 {"date": "2021-02-24T18:30:00.000Z",
  "age":"9",
  "id": 74,
  "time": 4.00
}];
```

I am getting all this data from API so next array will be like this:

```
let arr1 = [{
  "id": 1,
  "arrKey1": "schedule1"
  }, {
  "id": 2,
  "arrKey1": "schedule2"
  }]
let arr2 = [{
  "id": 1,
  "arrKey2": "bus1"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "arrKey2": "bus2"
}]
let arr3 = [{
  "id": 1,
  "arrKey3": "car1"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "arrKey3": "1"
}]
```

Now the result should reflect like this:

```
  [{
    "date": "2021-02-24T18:30:00.000Z",
    "age": "9",
    "id": 74,
    "time": 4.00,
    "arrKey1":"schedule1",
    "arrKey2 ":"bus1",
    "arrKey3":"car1"},
   {"date ": "2021-02-24T18:30:00.000Z",
    "age": "9",
    "id": 74,
    "time": 4.00,
    "arrKey1": "schedule2",
    "arrKey2": "bus2",
    "arrKey3": "1"
  }];
```

Comment: Please fix the syntax, and post what you've tried so far to solve this on your own.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: I saw that too late. Fixed it now

Comment: what if the `MainArray` has length more than 2 ? what would be expected o/p then?

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 you can use three dots. see the example:

```js
let MainArr = [1, 2, 3];
let arr1 = [4, 5, 6];

console.log('before: ', MainArr)
MainArr.push(...arr1)
console.log('after pushing arr1: ', MainArr)
```

Comment: This doesnt give correct output But i got it what you mean.

Comment: In my example or in your codes? In my example the `MainArr` is `[1, 2, 3]` at first. and after executing `MainArr.push(...arr1)`, the `MainArr` will equals to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. But if you tried using `...` and you did not get the correct output, you can share your codes with us to check theme out.

Comment: But here the case is different if i do this all the items in array will push i dont want id to push in those 3 arrays

Comment: So you need to use a `for` loop and i think there is no way instead

Comment: Yeah, i got it.I need to use the for Loop